# How to change default windows explorer copier for other

Tags: c#, windows, xcopy

I need this solution for install my own copier software (C#), please if somebody knows about  any register key or system 32 program to override windows default copier for another. I've been investigating months and nothing.

Comment: Please clarify what are you trying to do.

Comment: Install Teracopy and process monitor on your machine. Start process monitor and start teracopy. Change settings of teracopy to be default copier. Now in process monitor, see the registry entry it has changed. Uninstall teracopy later on.

Comment: How Teracopy and SuperCopy override Windows Default Copier?? , that is what i need

Comment: Thaks Sarvesh Mishra, is a great idea, i goin to try. Can you help me with the Monitor Process, there are tutorials or papers?

Answer (score 0):

Check for this, deprecated but maybe it helps. This code is part of a software similar to teracopy, i want to use it but i dont know anything about C++.

[Github Supercopier](https://github.com/alphaonex86/Supercopier)

Comment: Thanks i will write you if i find anything, I known a little of C++ with Qt.